# How to host .net tcpclient listner in azure virtual machine

Tags: c#, .net, azure, tcpclient, azure-virtual-machine

I have written the TCPClient Listener to listen to a particular port which will send HL7 data to it.
Code is working fine in local but we are facing issues when deploying to azure virtual machine.

> How to deploy TCPClientListner in azure virtual machine. Should it be a webservice or worker process?

I was going over the net but not able to get the solution.
Also looks like there's another option to deploy it in cloud services.

https://cuteprogramming.blog/2018/01/07/tcp-listener-on-microsoft-azure-for-iot-devices/

```
public class Program{
  static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
    {
        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
    }).Build();
    var config = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

    string IpAddress = config["IpAddress"];
    int port = Convert.ToInt32(config["port"]);

    TcpListener ourTcpListener;

    try
    {
        // Create a TCPListener to accept client connections through port 1080
        ourTcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(IpAddress), port);

        //start listening
        ourTcpListener.Start();

        Console.Write($"Started TCP Listener...{ourTcpListener.LocalEndpoint}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //if there was an error starting the listener then print the error and quit
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return;
    }

    var receivedByteBuffer = new byte[200];

    for (; ; )
    {
        // Run the listening loop forever
        // this will keep accepting and servicing client connections
        TcpClient acceptTcpClient = null;
        NetworkStream netStream = null;
        try
        {
            Console.Write("Waiting for incoming client connections...");

            acceptTcpClient = ourTcpListener.AcceptTcpClient(); // Get client connection
            netStream = acceptTcpClient.GetStream();

            Console.Write("Handling incoming client connection...");

            // Keep receiving data from the client closes connection
            var totalBytesReceivedFromClient = 0;
            int bytesReceived; // Received byte count
            while ((bytesReceived = netStream.Read(receivedByteBuffer, 0, receivedByteBuffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                if (netStream.CanWrite)
                {
                    //echo the received data back to the client
                    netStream.Write(receivedByteBuffer, 0, bytesReceived);
                }

                totalBytesReceivedFromClient += bytesReceived;
            }
            var receivedMsg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedByteBuffer);
            Console.WriteLine("Received Msgs:{0}", receivedMsg);
            Console.WriteLine("Echoed {0} bytes back to the client.", totalBytesReceivedFromClient);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //print any exceptions during the communications to the console
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close the stream and the connection with the client
            netStream?.Close();
            netStream?.Dispose();
            acceptTcpClient?.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What's the exact error you are seeing?